# Compare two items when rated by ordinal variables

Tags: ordinal-data, rating

This question was spurred by one of those tech support sites that asks at the bottom "rate how helpful this article was" and allows you to rate the article 5 for very helpful and 1 for not helpful at all.

What if you enlisted around 20 people, and had each of the 20 rate two of these tech support articles (not ten rate the first article and ten rate the second, but all 20 people rate each article).  Is there any statistically meaningful way to say which article is 'better' based on that survey?

Clearly, if one article was garnering mostly 5's and 4's while the other got mostly 1's and 2's it would probably stand to reason that the first is a better article, but what if the proportions were pretty close?  Is there a way to detect those slight differences?

The reason I ask about having all of the people rate both articles is because I am familiar with situations where you have two samples and can do some median comparisons with independent observations, but I'm curious what happens if you lose that assumption and instead have some dependence in the data.

Thanks for any responses.  I thought about this for a while and came up blank, so I was wondering what some other people would come up with.

Answer (score 0):

Wilcoxon signed-rank test would be appropriate to compare matched (by evaluator) ratings.